# A convolution identity (revision of the question "Is this convolution identity known?")

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convolution

I have deleted the content of the original post.

The following exercise is inspired by answers to the questions [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11487/y-xn-what-is-exyy) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/ex-1-x-1-x-2-for-independent-gamma-random-variables), but no knowledge of probability theory is required. The solution is straightforward assuming familiarity with the relevant theorems/properties. The proof is supposed to be informal.

Let $\hat \varphi (\omega)$ denote the Fourier transform of a function $\varphi$, and $*$ convolution.
Express $\hat g(\omega)$ in terms of $\hat f(\omega)$ and a constant $a \in (0,1)$, so that
$$
(f_2  * g)(t) = at(f * g)(t),
$$ 
where $f_2 (x) = xf(x)$.

Comment: If you know the solution, why are you asking the question?

Comment: Since it's interesting, probably not well-known (to say the least), motivated by some recent posts here, and since I found the solution only after the original question was posted (I formulated the original question too hastily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be messing up my usage of Fourier transforms and convolutions with distributions, but I think this can be solved with a few identities (namely how transforms work on products and convolutions, and how convolutions work with derivatives and Dirac deltas). Given the starting point $(xf) * g = a t (f * g)$, take the (unitary, ordinary frequency) transform to obtain

$(\hat{x}*\hat{f} ) \hat{g} = a\hat{x} * (\hat{f} \hat{g}) \implies (\delta'*\hat{f} ) \hat{g} = a\delta' * (\hat{f} \hat{g}) \implies \hat{f}' \hat{g} = a (\hat{f}\hat{g})'$

If you foil and rewrite you get the simple differential equation $a \hat{g} ' + (a-1) (\hat{f}' / \hat{f}) \hat{g} =0 $, which is easy to solve and comes out with $\hat{g} = \hat{f}^{1/a - 1}$ (I hope I did that all correctly!).

[EDIT - thanks to below comment.]

Comment: Almost. the diff-eq you should end up with is $a \hat{g}' + (a-1) (\hat{f}' / \hat{f}) \hat{g}$ = 0. So you need to change the power raised in your final answer a little bit.

Comment: That's what I get for using a bedside scrap of paper for scratchwork. :/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to chroma's answer, only that I get 
$$
(xf) * g = at(f * g) \Rightarrow \hat f'\hat g = a(\hat f \hat g)' 
$$
straight from the following standard property (combined, of course, with the convolution theorem):
if $\psi = x \varphi$, then $\hat \psi = i \hat \varphi'$.