# Questions regarding Martingales

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm trying to learn about Martingales with specific focus on combinatorial problems. However i'm far from an expert in algebra and am having some trouble understanding the basic idea. I will write the exact paragraph that i'm reading and then some areas where i'm struggling.

-- Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and an increasing sequence of sub-$\sigma$ fields $\mathcal{F}_{0}= \{\emptyset,\Omega\} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{1} \subseteq ... \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n}=\mathcal{F}$, a sequence of random variables $X_{0},X_{1},...,X_{n}$ (with finite expectations) is called a martingale if for each $k=0,...,n-1$, $\mathbb{E}(X_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_{k})=X_{k}$. In this case (with a finite sequence), every martingale is obtained from a random variable $X$ by taking $X_{k}=\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_{k})$, $k=0,...,n$. Then $X_{0}=\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $X_{n}=X$. Also, we always have $\mathbb{E}(X_{k+1})=\mathbb{E}(X_{k})$. --

Ok so i'm trying to keep everything within a combinatorial context specifically to random graphs.

So i know a sigma field on some set is a collection of subsets satisfying certain set theoretic properties (i.e for every subset containment of it's compliment). Can anyone give a combinatorial example of a sequence of increasing sigma fields?

Secondly i'm unsure how $X_{k}$ is defined. What exactly does $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_{k})$ mean? Is it the restriction of the random variable $X$ to the sigma field $\mathcal{F}_{k}$?

I think if someone could perhaps provide a concrete simple combinatorial example it would help me greatly. I appreciate any help!

Comment: think of increasing sigma fields as accumulation of information -- you perform an experiment and measure outcomes at each timestep. E(X|Fk) is a conditional expectation. Are there examples from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_%28probability_theory%29#Examples_of_martingales) you don't understand? See also [this question and answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690531/intuition-for-random-variable-being-sigma-algebra-measurable) as well as the linked ones.