# Is every $\sigma$-algebra generated by a partition?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I know that every finite $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a finite partition, but is every infinite $\sigma$-algebra also generated by "kind of" partition? Can anyone help provide a explanation or reference?

Thank you!

Comment: A countable $\sigma$-algebra is necessarily finite (i.e. an infinite $\sigma$-algebra is uncountable)

Comment: @Giovanni Thank you so much for pointing this out! I have edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

Borel $\sigma$ algebra $B[0,1])$ of the set $[0,1]$ is infinite but it is not generated  by any partition of the interval $[0.1]$. Assume the contrary and let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be such a partition.Since singletons belong to  $B[0,1])$ we deduce that each $X_i$ must be singleton. Then $[0,1/2]$ does not belong to $B[0,1])$ 
because it is not presented as union of countable singletons. The latter relation is the contradiction and we have proved that  $B[0,1])$ is an example of infinite  $\sigma$-algebra which is not generated by any partition of $[0.1]$.

Answer (score 3):

An *atom* in a measurable space $(M,\mathcal{M})$ is a nonempty set $A\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $B\in\mathcal{M}$ and $B\subseteq A$ implies that either $B=\emptyset$ or $B=A$. If $\mathcal{M}$ is generated by a countable family of sets, so it is *countably generated*,  every point in $M$ is in a unique atom and the atoms form a partition of $M$.

A countably generated measurable space $(M,\mathcal{M})$ is *strongly Blackwell* if any two countably generated sub-$\sigma$-algebras with the same atoms coincide. They are called that way because David Blackwell has shown that analytic spaces are strongly Blackwell in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200502002). This includes for example the unit interval with the Borel sets. So for strongly Blackwell spaces, there is a way to read the question so that the answer is yes.

Not every countably generated measurable space is strongly Blackwell. Just take the unit interval and take the $\sigma$-algebra to be generated by the open sets and one non-Borel set $N$. Then the atoms are the singleton sets but so are the atoms of the proper sub-$\sigma$-algebra consisting of the Borel sets. So the answer to the question is in general no.