# Conditional expectation $E(X|\mathcal{F})(\omega)=E[X|A_j]$.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I was reading [this interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690905/340973) of conditional expectation to try understand better conditional expectation and measurability. What I understood from it is that given a probability space $\Omega$ and $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ a partition of $\Omega$, if we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\{A_i\}_{i\in I})$, i.e. a $\sigma$-algebra which is generated by a partition of $\Omega$ then $E(X|\mathcal{F})(\omega)=E[X|A_j]$ if $\omega\in A_j$. However, the last step (6.) from the first linked post where the method is extended to any $\sigma$-algebra is not clear to me. Indeed there are some $\sigma$-algebras that are not generated by a partitions, like the Borel sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$ ([see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416233/340973)) and then it is not so clear to me how this technique works.

**Added**

Maybe there is something I am not getting right about how [step (6.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690905/340973) from the linked answer should work. I consider $([0,1],\mathcal{B},P)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ are the borel sets and $P$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. A partition of $[0,1]$ with borel sets (which doesn't generate the borelians since by the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416233/340973) this is not possible) would be $[0,1]= \sqcup_{\omega\in[0,1]}\{\omega\}$. However we know that $\omega\in \{\omega\}$ and by analogy with the linked answer we would like to have $E[X|\mathcal{B}]=E[X|\{\omega\}]= E[X:{\omega}]/P(\{\omega\})$ but $P(\{x\})=0$ so this is not well defined. In general $\omega\in (\omega-\epsilon,\omega+\epsilon)$ then we also have $\omega\in (\omega-\epsilon/2,\omega+\epsilon/2)$ or $\omega\in (\omega-\epsilon/3,\omega+\epsilon/3)$ or whatever. But how do you define $E[X|\mathcal{B}]$? Indeed, $W[X|(\omega-\epsilon,\omega+\epsilon)]$, $W[X|(\omega-\epsilon/2,\omega+\epsilon/2)]$ or $W[X|(\omega-\epsilon/3,\omega+\epsilon/3)]$ are different. I just don't understand how point 6) works in this case.

Comment: You mentioned that $E[X|(\omega-\frac1n,\omega+\frac1n)]$ ($n\in \mathbb N^+$) are all different. However, under suitable conditions, you can say that 
$$E[X|\omega]=\lim_{n\to\infty} E[X|(\omega-\frac1n,\omega+\frac1n)]$$
More generally, under suitable conditions
$$
E[X|\mathcal F](\omega)=\lim_{F\searrow \{\omega\}} E[X|F]
$$
Here, the limit is taken through set $F\in \mathcal F$ containing $\omega$ for which $P(F)>0$, meaning the conditional expectation on the right is well defined. The suitable conditions are that $\Omega$ is a topological space, and $P$ is a Radon measure.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, interesting. Do you have any reference suggestion developing this idea?

Comment: I know that my comment can me made rigorous whenever a "regular conditional probability" exists. Googling that phrase should give some answers. I'm afraid I am not familiar enough with the subject to explain more.

Answer (score 2):

There is a geometric way to look at this. Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ and $L_2(P)$ the space of real valued $\mathscr{F}$-measurable functions $X$ such that $E[|X|^2]<\infty$.
If you have develop enough integration theory, it turns our that $L_2(P)$ (once functions $X$, $Y$  with $P(X\neq Y)=0$ are identified) is a nice Hilbert space, that is a complete inner product  where
$$\langle X,Y\rangle=E[XY]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)Y(\omega)\,P(d\omega)$$

In the examples where you have a measurable finite partition of $\Omega$, say $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}\subset\mathscr{F}$, $A_j\cap A_k=\emptyset$ if $j\neq k$, $P[A_j]>0$ for all $j$, and $\Omega=\bigcup^n_{j=1}A_k$, the functions $Y_j=\mathbb{1}_{A_j}$ are orthogonal: $E[Y_jY_k]=P[A_j\cap A_k]=0$ if $j\neq k$. The expected value of a given random variable $X$ given $\mathcal{A}$ is
$$
E[X|\mathcal{A}]=\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{E[A\mathcal{1}_{A_j}]}{P{A_j}}\mathbb{1}_{A_j}=\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{E[XY_j]}{E[Y_j^2]}Y_j$$
which is the same is the orthogonal projection of $X$ on the the linear space spanned by $\{Y_1,\ldots, Y_k\}$. Notice that
$E\big[Y_j(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}]\big]=0$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$.

This can be generalized to any other $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G}\subset\mathscr{F}$, for the orthogonal projection of a function $L_2(P)$ onto the closure (in the $L_2(P)$-norm) of the linear space generated by the functions in $L_2(P)$ that are $\mathscr{G}$-measurable always [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthogonal_complements_and_projections).

Thus, if $X\in L_2(P)$, $E[X|\mathscr{G}]$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto the closure (in $L_2(P)$ if the linear space generated by $L_2(P)$ functions that are $\mathscr{G}$-measurable.

For functions $X\in L_1(P)$, there is a more sophisticated way to defined $E[X|\mathscr{G}]$, for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G}\subset\mathscr{F}$ through a result known as the Radon-Nikodym theorem. The Radon-Nikodym theorem in turn can be proved using $L_2(P)$ methods (for example Rudin, W. Real Complex Analysis, 3rd edition, McGraw-Hill, pp. 121-122).

Comment: I had to think a while about your answer. I think the geometrical interpretation of conditional expectation you present is nice. However it seems different than the one from the linked answer. I am having a hard time understanding if the method of the said answer just works for $\sigma$-algebras that are generated by a partition of the sample space $\Omega$ or if it would work for general $\sigma$-algebras. I added what was troubling me.

Comment: That is the point, the method in your reference works fine form $\sigma$-algbras generated by finte (and even countable) partitions. The expressions obtained for the conditional expectations then become reminiscent to orthogonal projections. That is the main idea developed by Doob in the 1940's.