# Identity on $L^1(\Omega, G, P)$ of $E(X | G)$ when $X$ is $G$-measurable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X \in L^1(\Omega, F, P)$, and $G \subset F$. I'm struggling to show that the identity $E(X | G) = X$ holds whenever $X$ is $G$-measurable. I think I understand the intuition behind this identity, as explained by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690947), namely that "$G$ contains all information about $X$, so by knowing $G$ you can recover $X$".

But again, I don't think I've understood this completely yet. Specifically, I'm having trouble in showing the identity from the partial averaging property:
$$ \int_A E(X |G) dP = \int_A X dP \quad \forall A \in G.$$

The proofs I've looked up state that it's obvious that $E(X | G) = X$, so I hope you can clarify what I'm missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By definition $E(X|G)=X$ holds if

a) $X$ is measurable w.r.t. $G$

b) $\int_A XdP=\int_A XdP$ for all $A \in G$.

Both of these are obvious.

Comment: So what you're saying that it's a definition (point a), and nothing needs to be shown/proven? (And in point b you've written $\int_A X dp =  \int_A X dp$, $\forall A \in G$, did you mean to write that?)