# Formal definition of conditional probability

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, expectation

It would be extremely helpful if anyone gives me the formal definition of conditional probability and expectation in the following setting, given probability space 
$ (\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mu ) $ with $\mu(\Omega) = 1 $, and a random variable $ X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $, where for any borel set $ A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ we define 
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \in A) = (X_*\mu)(A) = \mu(X^{-1}(A))=
\mu(\{\omega\in \Omega\ \ |\ \ X(\omega)
\in A\})\ \ \text{and}\ \ \mathbb{E}(X) = \int_\Omega Xd\mu $$
Regardless of $X, Y$ being discrete or continuous (with density $f_X, f_Y $ and joint density $f_{X,Y} $ w.r.t some measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n $), I am asking for the definition 
of $ \mathbb{P}(Y\in B\ |\ X \in A) $ and $ \mathbb{E}(Y|X) $  for all Borel sets $ A, B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) $, keeping in mind that $ \mathbb{P}(X \in A) $ may well be zero.

In our probability class some thing of the following sort was mentioned, where
$\delta_x$ is the Dirac distribution at $ x $, then we have
$$ \mathbb{E}(Y|X = x) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\delta_x(X)Y)}{\mathbb{P}(X=x)}$$
out of which I can't make any sense. Any appropiate reference for these is also very much welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You can find a formal definition for conditional expectation (with some nice discussion regarding what it represents) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/intuition-behind-conditional-expectation) and (with its main properties) [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec9.pdf). Maybe you can review these and answer your own question?

Comment: $E(Y|X=x)$ that you mention denotes the conditional expectation of the random variable $Y$ with respect to the sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ generated by the sets of the form $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)=x\}$. It turns out that for sigma algebras generated by disjoint sets $A_i$, $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ evaluated on $A_i$ is equal to $$\frac{E(1_{A_i}Y)}{P(A_i)},$$ where $1_A$ denotes the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$. See page 220 of [this](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf).

Comment: I can't remember of a definition for the probability of an event $\{Y\in B\}$ conditioned on a second event $\{X\in A\}$ apart from the standard undergrad definition if $P(\{X\in A\})\neq 0$ of $$P(\{Y\in B\}|\{X\in A\}):=\frac{P(\{Y\in B\}\cap \{X\in A\})}{P(\{X\in A\})}.$$ I forgot to add the sets $A_i$ above must each have positive probability for the equality to hold.

Comment: Sorry I should have said page 191 - confusion with editions ...

Answer (score 90):

Let throughout this post $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, and let us first define the conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$ for integrable random variables $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $X\in L^1(P)$, and sub-sigma-algebras $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

> **Definition**: *The conditional expectation ${\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$ of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$* is the random variable $Z$ having the following properties:
>
> (i) $Z$ is integrable, i.e. $Z\in L^1(P)$.
>
> (ii) $Z$ is ($\mathcal{G},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable.
>
> (iii) For any $A\in\mathcal{G}$ we have 
>   $$
> \int_A Z\,\mathrm dP=\int_A X\,\mathrm dP.
> $$

Note: It makes sense to talk about *the* conditional expectation since if $U$ is another random variable satisfying (i)-(iii) then $U=Z$ $P$-a.s.

> **Definition**: If $X\in L^1(P)$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is any random variable, then *the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$* is defined as
>   $$
> {\rm E}[X\mid Y]:={\rm E}[X\mid\sigma(Y)],
> $$
>   where $\sigma(Y)=\{Y^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $Y$.

I'm not aware of any other definition of $P(Y\in B\mid X\in A)$ than the obvious, i.e.
$$
P(Y\in B\mid X\in A)=\frac{P(Y\in B,X\in A)}{P(X\in A)}
$$
provided that $P(X\in A)>0$. The only exception being when $A$ contains a single point, i.e. $A=\{x\}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case, the object $P(Y\in B\mid X=x)$ is defined in terms of a regular conditional distribution.

Let us first define regular conditional probabilities. Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a random variable.

> **Definition**: *A regular conditional probability for $P$ given $X$* is a function 
>   $$
> \mathcal{F}\times \mathbb{R} \ni(A,x)\mapsto P^X(A\mid x)
> $$
>   satisfying the following three conditions:
>
> (i) The mapping $A\mapsto P^X(A\mid x)$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (ii) The mapping $x\mapsto P^X(A\mid x)$ is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$.
>
> (iii) The defining equation holds: For any $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
>   $$
> \int_B P^X(A\mid x)\,P_X(\mathrm dx)=P(A\cap\{X\in B\}).
> $$

Note: A mapping satisfying (i) and (ii) is often called a Markov kernel. Furthermore, since $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a nice space, the regular conditional probability is unique in the sense that if $\tilde{P}^X(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ is another regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$, then we have that $P^X(\cdot\mid x)=\tilde{P}^X(\cdot\mid x)$ for $P_X$-a.a. $x$. Here $P_X=P\circ X^{-1}$ is the distribution of $X$.

> **Connection**: Let $P^X(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ be a regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$. Then for any $A\in\mathcal{F}$ we have
>   $$
> {\rm E}[1_A\mid X]=\varphi(X),
> $$
>   where $\varphi(x)=P^X(A\mid x)$. In short we write ${\rm E}[1_A\mid X]=P^X(A\mid X)$.

Now let us introduce another random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, and $P^X(\cdot\mid \cdot)$ still denotes a regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$.

> **Definition**: For $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we define *the regular conditional distribution* of $Y$ given $X$ by
>   $$
> P_{Y\mid X}(B\mid x):=P^X(Y\in B\mid x).
> $$

Instead of $P_{Y\mid X}(B\mid x)$ one often writes $P(Y\in B\mid X=x)$.

An easy consequence of this definition is that $(B,x)\mapsto P_{Y\mid X}(B\mid x)$ is a Markov kernel and for any $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$
\int_A P_{Y\mid X}(B\mid x)\,P_X(\mathrm dx)=P(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\}). \tag{1}
$$

In fact, $P_{Y\mid X}(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ is a regular conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ if and only if $P_{Y\mid X}(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ is a Markov kernel and satisfies $(1)$. Again $(1)$ is often referred to as the defining equation.

> **Definition**: Let $P^X(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ be a regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$. Furthermore, let $U:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be another random variable that is assumed bounded (to ensure the following expectations exist). Then we define *the (regular) conditional mean of $U$ given $X=x$* by 
>   $$
> {\rm E}[U\mid X=x]:=\int_\Omega U(\omega)\, P^X(\mathrm d\omega\mid x).
> $$

Let us denote $\psi(x)={\rm E}[U\mid X=x]$. Then we have the following:

> **Connection**: The mapping $\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto \psi(x)$ is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable, and
>   $$
> {\rm E}[U\mid X]=\psi(X).
> $$

The following is an extremely useful rule when calculating with conditional distributions:

> **Rule**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be as above, and let $\xi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. Then
>   $$
> P(\xi(X,Y)\in D\mid X=x)=P(\xi(x,Y)\in D\mid X=x),\quad D\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),
> $$
>   holds for $P_X$-a.a. $x$. This is saying that "conditional on $X=x$ we may replace $X$ by $x$".

The following example shows how this rule can be useful: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables, and let $U=X+Y$. Then we claim that $U\mid X=x\sim \mathcal{N}(x,1)$ for $P_X$-a.a. $x$. To see this, note that by the rule above, the distribution of $U\mid X=x$ and $Y+x\mid X=x$ is the same. But since $Y$ is independent of $X$ we have that $Y+x\mid X=x$ is distributed as $Y+x$. We can write it as follows:
$$
U\mid X=x\sim Y+x\mid X=x\sim Y+x\sim\mathcal{N}(x,1).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my incentive of asking for $ P(X \in B | X \in A) $ was to understand conditioning on measure 0 sets, for e.g. iids $X_1,X_2\sim exp(\lambda)$ to find $ P(X_1+X_2 \in A|X_1 = X_2) $ gives two different answers, by conditioning on $ \{X_1-X_2= 0\} $ and $\{X_1/X_2 = 1\} $ respectively....

Comment: Could you update your question with the derivation of these two answers?

Comment: Routine calculations involving change of variables in two cases above, give you $ P(X_1 +X_2 \in A| X_1 = X_2) $ as $ \int_A\lambda^2 ye^{-\lambda y}dy $ for $ P(X_1 + X_2 \in A | X_1-X_2 = 0) $and $ \int_A\lambda ye^{-\lambda y}dy $ for $ P(X_1 + X_2 \in A | X_1/X_2 = 1)$ respectively.

Comment: Could you please show these routine calculations?

Comment: amazing! Most complete explanation I have found on understanding conditional probabilities. Thanks.

Comment: @StefanHansen Do you know or have a reference to a proof for the replacement rule? I couldn't prove it [myself](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268041/proof-of-replacement-rule-in-conditional-probability).

Comment: @simonzack: Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/probability-distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables).

Comment: @smiley06 I've asked the same question myself. Basically, if $P(A)=0$, $P(B|A)$ can be meaningfully defined *as a standalone quantity* only if $B\cap A=\emptyset$ or $B\cap A^c=\emptyset$ (with values of $P(B|A)$ respectively $0$ and $1$) - otherwise different transformations/limiting procedures would yield different values. Similarly, $E(Y|A)$ makes sense only if $Y$ is constant on $A$ - otherwise you can obtain any $y\in[\inf_A Y,\sup_A Y]$ as a value. And to finish, $Y|A$ can be any distribution on range of $Y$ restricted to $A$. I just posted a similar question: http://tiny.cc/935x6x

Comment: @A.S. exactly so......that's why I wanted to know if there is a unique definition in such a situation.

Comment: @smiley There isn't. ["The concept of a conditional probability with regard to an isolated hypothesis whose probability equals 0 is inadmissible."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox#Explanation_and_implications) IIRC, there are developments of probability that somehow allow conditioning on sets of measure $0$.

Comment: @StefanHansen: A question concerning the definition of r.c.p.: All the other people do it like this: $\nu: \Omega \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ and demand that $\nu(\cdot, B) = E[1_{X \in B}|\mathcal{F}]$ i.e. we should suspect that $\nu(\omega, B) = P^X(X^{-1}(B), X(\omega))$ but this does not work: when integrating over an arbitrary set $A$ then $1_A$ is not factorizable... Could you elaborate? Are these two different definitions of r.c.p.?

Comment: @FabianWerner: I don't follow your construction. First, why do you condition on $\mathcal{F}$? Since $X$ is a random variable, $\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X\in B}\mid \mathcal{F}]=\mathbf{1}_{X\in B}$, no? Second, how do you make sense of $P^X(X^{-1}(B),X(\omega))$ since $P^X$ is a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and does not take two arguments?

Comment: @StefanHansen: sorry, $\mathcal{F}$ was an unclever special case. Generally, for example, in http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf 5.1.3 on p. 197 they define thr r.c.p. w.r.t. any sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ as a map $\mu : \Omega \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0,1]$, i.e. going from the target sigma algebra  times the original space to the reals while in your case, $P^X$ goes from the original sigma algebra times the target space... see the twist [original <-> target]? Does your definition coincide somehow with 5.1.3 in the reference?

Comment: @FabianWerner: Sorry, I misread your $P^X$ as $P_X$, so nevermind that previous comment of mine. This is a good question though. So, in this post we do not define r.c.p's with respect to a general sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ but only with respect to $\mathcal{G}$'s of the form $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$. The r.c.p. can then be defined as $P^X(A\mid x):=\varphi_A(x)$, where $\varphi_A$ is the function satisfying $\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_A\mid X]=\varphi_A(X)$ (Connection 1). I believe the relationship is $\mu(\omega,A)=\varphi(X(\omega))=P^X(A\mid X(\omega))$.

Comment: So I actually believe that Durrett's definition is more general but is equivalent to this definition when $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$ (Note that I use $X$ to condition on, whereas he uses it differently).

Comment: @StefanHansen Careful: There is an additional twist: $\mu$ does not accept sets from $\mathcal{F}$ but rather from the target sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Thats why I inserted that $X^{-1}(...)$ in the twist. Hmm... But if we can easily construct their $\mu$ from your $P^X$ then I have the feeling that your defn. should be more general (although as said, I can only show that $\mu = P^X(X^{-1}, X)$ if $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$... weird...

Comment: The thing is that the case $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$ is boring as one uses this often with $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$ from another random variable $Y$. Anyhow, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @FabianWerner: But r.c.p.'s in Durrett is defined by letting $(S,\mathcal{S})=(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $X:\Omega\to\Omega$ be the identity in which case $\mu$ does accept sets from $\mathcal{F}$. You seem to have misunderstood me. For r.c.p.'s there is only _one_ random variable (the one we condition on). Just replace $\sigma(X)$ with $\sigma(Y)$ in my previous comment (I just used $X$ to condition on since this is what I did in my initial post, although Durrett uses $X$ differently).

Comment: Yes, sorry, whenever I wrote r.c.p. I actually meant the more general r.c.d. (without fixing G). Now it becomes at least clear to me that $\mu$ (if defined on $\sigma(X)$) and $P^X$ if only evaluated on sets $A \in \sigma(X)$ coincide in the sense that $\mu = P^X(X^{-1}, X)$ and $P^X$ on $(A, x)$ is $A = X^{-1}(B) = X^{-1}(B')$ then $X \in B == X \in B'$ and thus $E[1_{X \in B}|\sigma(x)] = E[1_{X \in B'}|\sigma(x)]$ and factorizing this into $f_A \circ X$ yields $P^X = f_A(x)$. I.e. they coincide 'on' $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: @FabianWerner: So whenever $\mathcal{G}$ is of the form $\sigma(Y)$ for _any_ random variable $Y$ and if $\varphi$ is the function satisfying $\varphi_A(Y)=\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X\in A}\mid Y]$, then $\mu(\omega,A)=\varphi_A(Y(\omega))$ whereas $P_{X\mid Y}(A\mid y)=\varphi_A(y)$. So the two ways of definining r.c.d's are essentially the same, however Durrett's definition allows for condtioning on an arbitrary sigma-algebra, whereas this definition only allows conditioning on a sigma-algebra generated by another random variable.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for such a great answer. May I ask you from which source or textbook you got these definitions?

Comment: @julypraise: These are from lecture notes used at my local university at the time I studied. I think they are pretty much consistent with the notation used in the series Probability With a View Towards Statistics by Hoffmann-Jørgensen.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen Hi, this is a very good answer. Could you give me a reference for the things you wrote here, so that I can learn more about it. Thks.

Comment: @Hana: See my comment just above yours.