# $X=U_1, Y=U_1+U_2$ find $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X=U_1$, $Y=U_1+U_2$ and $U_1,U_2$ are independent. How to find find $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$?

This is the problem from `Probability. Statistics. and Random Processes for EE  Problem 6.12.`

The answer is $f_{U_2}(y-x)$. But I have no idea how to find it.

Based on the basic definition: $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$, then I have no idea of what the next step is.

Based on the answer, that could be $f_{Y-X}(y-x)$. However, I cannot find the relation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "[replacement rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268041/proof-of-replacement-rule-in-conditional-probability)" and that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent:

$$F_{Y|X}(y|x)=P\{U_1+U_2\le y\mid U_1=x\}=P\{U_2\le y-x\}=F_{U_2}(y-x)$$

---

**Edit**: Let $\mathcal F$ be the $\sigma$-field, $U_1\in \mathcal{F}$ and $U_2$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$. For a function $\varphi$ with $\mathbb{E}|\varphi(U_1,U_2)|<\infty$ and $g(u_1)=\mathbb{E}\varphi(u_1, U_2)$ we have

$$\mathbb{E}[\varphi(U_1,U_2)\mid \mathcal F]=g(U_1).$$

You can find the reference in [Durrett's](https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) book (section 6.2). In your case $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(U_1)$ and

$$\varphi(U_1,U_2)=1\{U_1+U_2\le y\}.$$

Comment: I am a bit confused about the last equality; how do you omit $X=x$

Comment: @sleevechen Added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}f_{U_1+U_2\mid U_1}(y\mid x) & = \dfrac{f_{U_1+U_2,U_1}(y, x)}{f_{U_1}(x)} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{f_{U_2,U_1}(y-x, x)}{f_{U_1}(x)} \\[1ex] & =\dfrac{f_{U_2}(y-x)f_{U_1}( x)}{f_{U_1}(x)} \\[1ex] & =f_{U_2}(y-x)\end{align}$

---

By analogy to discrete random variables:

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(U_1+U_2=y\mid U_1= x) & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(U_1+U_2=y,U_1= x)}{\mathsf P(U_1=x)} \\[1ex] & = \dfrac{\mathsf P(U_2=y-x,U_1=x)}{\mathsf P(U_1=x)} \\[1ex] & =\dfrac{\mathsf P(U_2=y-x)\mathsf P(U_1=x)}{\mathsf P(U_1=x)} \\[1ex] & =\mathsf P(U_2=y-x)\end{align}$