# Why Does $\rm{E}[1_A \mid X] = P^X(A\mid X)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Following the excellent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496608/formal-definition-of-conditional-probability), it is stated that

> **Connection**: Let $P^X(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ be a regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$.  Then for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we have
>   $$
> {\rm E}[1_A\mid X]=\varphi(X),
> $$
>   where $\varphi(x) = P^X(A\mid x)$.  In short we write ${\rm E}[1_A\mid X]=P^X(A\mid X)$.

I'm trying to prove this for myself, but I'd appreciate some help.  We need to show two things:

1. $P^X(A\mid X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable
2. $\rm{E}[1_C P^X(A\mid X)] = \rm{E}[1_C 1_A]$ for all $C \in \sigma(X)$.

Since $P^X(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ is a regular conditional probability, we know that for fixed $A \in \mathcal{F}$, the mapping $x \mapsto P^X(A\mid x)$ is $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable.  Hence the composition $P^X(A\mid \cdot) \circ X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable for fixed $A \in \mathcal{F}$, which the author writes as $P^X(A\mid \cdot) \circ X = P^X(A|X)$.  Thus $P^X(A\mid X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, and we have 1.

For 2, recall that for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ the conditional probability  is defined to satisfy
$$
\int_B P^X(A\mid x) \,d\mu_X(x) = P(A \cap \{X \in B\}),
$$
where $\mu_X$ is the distribution measure of $X$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.  **This is the part I'm having trouble with.**  Here's my attempt:
\begin{align*}
\rm{E}[1_C P^X(A\mid X)] & = \int_{\Omega} 1_C(\omega)P^X(A\mid X)(\omega) dP(\omega) \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{1\}}(x) P^X(A\mid x)d\mu_X(x) &\qquad& (2) \\
& = \int_{\{1\}}P^X(A\mid x)d\mu_X(x) \\
& = P(A \cap \{X = 1\}) \\
& = \int_\Omega 1_A(\omega) 1_{\{X = 1\}}(\omega) dP(\omega) \\
& = \int_\Omega 1_A(\omega) 1_C(\omega) dP(\omega) &\qquad& (6) \\
& = \rm{E}[1_A 1_C].
\end{align*}

I'm almost certain lines (2) and (6) aren't true, but I'm not sure how else to write the indicator random variable when transitioning to the distribution measure in (2).  For (6), I don't see why $\{X = 1\} = C$, either, but it's my best shot at it right now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $C\in\sigma(X)$ can be written as $X^{-1}(B)=\{X\in B\}$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and hence $\mathbf{1}_C=\mathbf{1}_B(X)$. Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_CP^X(A\mid X)]=\int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_B(X)P^X(A\mid X)\,\mathrm dP=\int_BP^X(A\mid x)\,P_X(\mathrm dx)=P(A\cap \{X\in B\}).
$$
But
$$
P(A\cap \{X\in B\})=P(A\cap C)=\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_A\mathbf{1}_C]
$$
which is what we want.