# $\mathrm E [f(X,Y) \mid Y=y] = \mathrm E [f(X,y)]$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ be **independent** integrable random variables and let $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable.  It makes intuitive sense that 
$$
\mathrm E [f(X,Y) \mid Y=y] = \mathrm E [f(X,y)],
$$
but I'm having trouble showing this.  Does this only hold if $Y$ is discrete?  I'd like to show it rigorously using regular conditional probabilities, so starting out I would have
$$
\mathrm E [f(X,Y) \mid Y=y] = \int_{\Omega} (f \circ (X,Y))(\omega)\, P^Y(\mathrm d\omega \mid y),
$$
where $P^Y(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ is the regular conditional probability of $P$ given $Y$.  I'm really not sure how to proceed form here, so any help is appreciated.

**Update**:  Added that $X$ and $Y$ should be independent.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with your notation. Do you mean you are conditioning on the $\sigma$-algebra created by the set $ \{ Y = y \} $?

Comment: @kummerer94 Not quite, as $\mathrm E [f(X,Y) \mid Y=y]$ is not a conditional expectation w.r.t. a sigma-algebra, but rather a function $y \mapsto \mathrm E [f(X,Y) \mid Y=y]$, which is defined to be this integral.  I'm using notation from this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496608/formal-definition-of-conditional-probability

Comment: Oh! Quite interesting, I mistook it completely. I will need to dig deeper into the definitions to help here. Thanks so far!

Comment: @kummerer94 If you'd like to get your feet wet, perhaps you could help me with this seemingly simple problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372960/mathrm-e-x-mid-x-x-x

Comment: The identity you are interested in holds only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. // What is the source from which you copy this string of questions about conditional expectations?

Comment: @Did The source did assume they were independent, thanks for noticing.  I updated my question.

Comment: Bis: *What is the source from which you copy this string of questions about conditional expectations?*

Comment: @Did It was from a solutions document for Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II.  Why?

Answer (score 4):

To flesh out Did's comment: let $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=1/2$. Let $Y=-X$ and note that $X,Y$ are not independent. Then define $f(x,y)=x+y$.

$0=E[X+Y|Y=1]\neq E[X+1]=1.$