# On the conditional expectation of Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In general, one can prove that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_t=x]=f(x)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $X_t$ is the Ito process: $\mathrm{d}X_t=a(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}t+b(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t$.
Suppose now I have to evaluate
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^Tc(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t\bigg|X_t=x\right]
$$

Is it $\displaystyle \int_0^T c(t,x)\mathrm{d}W_t$ or $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^Tc(t,x)\mathrm{d}W_t\right]=0$? The correct answer should be the second but is this coherent with $(1)$?

Comment: "In general, one can prove"… I don't think so.

Comment: I just generalized this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1373480

Comment: The answer you linked regards $E(X\mid X=x)$. $E(f(X_t) \mid X_0 = x)$ does not have anything to do with that. If you had instead wrote $E(f(X_t)\mid X_t = x) = f(x)$, then that would have been okay, though to be pedantic, it's really $E(f(X_t) \mid X_t = x) = f(x)$ for $P$-almost sure $x$ where $P$ denotes the law of $X_t$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Now it should be correct

Comment: I don't think this question makes sense. Maybe you could give some context for this question?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Feynman-Kac formula to solve a parabolic PDE (Black-Scholes model for option pricing). It works out if $$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^Tc(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t\bigg|X_t=x\right]=0
$$ but I can't find a way to legitimize such step

Answer (score 2):

The statement you want to prove is valid if the integral is a true martingale.

Indeed it is an elementary property of the stochastic integral to have null expectation if it is a martingale.

A suffcient condition for the integral $\int_{0}^{t}c(\omega, s) dM_s$ to be a martingale on $[0,T]$ is that:

1. $c(w,s)$ is adapted and measurable in $s$
2. $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{T}c^2(\omega, s)ds] < \infty$

If, in particular, $M_t$ is a martingale and $c$ is bounded, then it can be proved that the integral is also a martingale.

If in general $M_t$ is only a local martingale we can't say much about that expectation.

Comment: Yes, $W_t$ is definitely a martingale. But my point is **why should the expectation be calculated in the first place**? Why is that $$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\big[f(t,X_t)\big|X_t=x\big]=f(t, x)\tag{1}$$ while for an (Ito) integral $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t_0}^T g(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}W_t\bigg\vert X_t=x\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t_0}^T g(t,x)\mathrm{d}W_t\right]=0$$ instead of simply $\int_{t_0}^Tg(t,x)\mathrm{d}W_t\neq 0 $, coherently with $(1)$?