# Under what conditions does a specified conditional distribution exist

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

It is common to see conditional distributions specified in stats like:

$$(X \mid \mu = t) \sim \mathcal{N} (t, 1)$$

(Of course, we can also use some other distribution here)

How do you prove that such a conditional probability actually exists, in terms of a [regular conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496608/formal-definition-of-conditional-probability)? And is there some condition on the underlying probability space?

Proofs and/or references appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the result you need: Theorem B.18 in the Appendix of the following lecture notes http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf

Comment: @Calculon Isn't that proving the existence of a conditional probability given P? How do we construct P here?

Comment: your interpretation of the result is correct but i don't think constructing $P$ is an issue here. if you take your space to be the real line, which would be sufficient for your example, then you satisfy all the conditions for the theorem to work.

Comment: @Calculon Still don't get how these two relate, can you make it a bit more explicit? I think $X$, $\mu$, $P$ all need to be constructed here.

Comment: I am not sure if I am about to say is correct. But if you pick an arbitrary (continuous) prior distribution for $\mu$ (one whose support contains $t$), you will have a joint distribution of $X$ and $\mu$. There will be some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},P)$ that accomodates $X$ and $\mu$ with the prescribed joint distribution. From that point on you just apply the theorem with $\sigma(\mu)$ as your sub sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: For future readers, the complete proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552329/regular-conditional-probabilities-a-confusion-about-an-existence-proof-from-thi).

Answer (score 5):

On a polish space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, a regular conditional distribution exists, that is, given any $\mathcal{G}$ sub-sigma algebra there is a function $K: \Omega\times \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ such that

1) $K(\omega, \cdot)$ is a probability measure

2) $K(\cdot, A)$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable

3) $K(\cdot, A) = \Bbb{E}[1_A \mid \mathcal{G}]$ $P$ almost surely

Moreover, if $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{G}$ is countably generated ($\mathcal{H} = \sigma(H_n, n \in \Bbb{N})$) then the following substitution principle holds:

4) There is a null set $N\in \mathcal{G}$: 
$$K(\omega,A) = 1_A(\omega) \quad A \in \mathcal{H}, \omega\in \Omega \setminus N$$

An interesting case occurs when $\mu$ is a random variable taking values on $\Bbb{R}$ since $\sigma(\mu)$ is countably generated we have that

$$K(\omega,\{\omega'\mid \{\mu(\omega') = \mu(\omega)\}) = 1, \quad \omega\in \Omega \setminus N$$

So almost surely $K(\omega, \cdot)$ is concentrated on the level set $\{\mu(\omega') = \mu(\omega)\}$

In the case you are dealing with, you know further (by assumption) that if $\mu(\omega )= t$
$$K(\omega, A) = \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\big(\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}\big)\, dx$$
that is, $K(\omega, \cdot) \sim N(\mu(\omega, 1))$ almost surely.

References for this can be found in

Parthasarathy, K. R., Probability Measures on Metric Spaces 1967.

Karatzas and Schreve - Brownian motion and stochastic calculus [chap 5, pag 306] 1991

and in the notes pointed out by Calculon:Theorem B.18 in the Appendix of the following lecture notes math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf