# Measure-theoretic definition of conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

I am trying to reconcile the formal definition of conditional probability via measure theory (as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496608/formal-definition-of-conditional-probability) question's answer and the Wikipedia definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation)) with the more elementary definitions of conditional probability given in early probability courses.

By elementary definitions, I mean the following: for two continuous real-valued r.v. $X, Y$ which have densities $f_X, f_Y$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure), we define the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ to be $$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} \text{ when } f_Y(y) > 0$$ where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint density of $X,Y$ (with respect to the product measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$). We have similar equations in the mixture (discrete-continuous) and discrete-discrete cases, as given on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case).

**Question**: How can we derive these "definitions" from the more general notions of conditional probability distributions defined via measure theory?

I am also trying to make sense of things like $f_{X,Y|Z}(x,y|z)$, i.e. the conditional density/distribution of $X,Y$ given $Z$ (which could be any combination of discrete and continuous r.v.'s or even taking values in a general space). It seems cumbersome to have to define all these cases in the elementary way. I hope answering my question will also clarify this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how the "elementary" definition of conditional *density* fits in the abstract measure-theoretical one?

Comment: @user587192: Yes, that's right. More generally, there is also the mixture case which involves probability mass *and* density functions (as in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case) given in the question). How do all of these fit in with the abstract measure-theoretic definition?