# Why does $\mathbb P(X<y+1\mid Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y+1} f_{(X\mid Y)}(x\mid y) \,dx$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have found this equality online and I am struggling to understand how/why it holds.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{y+1} f_{(X\mid Y)}(x\mid y)\,dx\,dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P(X<y+1 \mid Y=y)\,dy$$

Is this correct? If so, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_{(X|Y)}(\cdot| y)$ is the density of $P(\cdot | Y=y),$ then
$$\int_{- \infty}^{y+1} f_{(X|Y)}(x|y) dx = P(X \leq y+1 | Y=y)$$
follows by definition. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498338/382972) for a very good description.