# what is exactly the $\sigma -$algebra $\mathcal F_T=\{A\in \mathcal F\mid A\cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t\}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space, $\{\mathcal F_t\}$ a filtration and $T$ a stopping time. We denote $$\mathcal F_T=\{A\in \mathcal F\mid A\cap \{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t\}.$$

What is exactly this $\sigma -$algebra ? What it represent concretely ?

Comment: What do you mean by "concretely"? You might want to take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2401241/36150) which is about the intuition behind $\mathcal{F}_T$.

Comment: Here $A$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal F$ and if its intersection with $\{T\leqslant t\}$ is an element of $\mathcal F_t$, then $A\in \mathcal F_T$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verifying the interpretation of stopping times and stopping time $\sigma$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401241/verifying-the-interpretation-of-stopping-times-and-stopping-time-sigma-algebr)