# Conditional expectation should be $\cal F$ a measurable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition, conditional-expectation

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23613/340973) that gives some intuition about what conditional expectation is. I can more or less understand it now but at some point in the response it is written :

> A single numerical response is not enough because the particular piece
> of information that I will give you is **itself random**. In fact,
> your response is necessarily a function of this particular piece of
> information.
> Mathematically, this is reflected in the requirement that ${\mathbb E}(X\ |\ {\cal F})$ must be $\cal F$ measurable.

How can I see that this mathematically translate to ${\mathbb E}(X\ |\ {\cal F})$ is $\cal F$ measurable?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma algebra generated by event $A$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})(\omega) = C_1\cdot \mathbb{1}_A(\omega) + C_2\cdot \mathbb{1}_{A^C}(\omega)$$
Hence, if we know whether or not event $A$ happened, we know this value. That is essentially what the measurability means intuitively.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Does measurability intuitively means this? I just know the definition that tells that the inverse image of a set should be in $\cal{F}$, or something like this. But how to link this definition with what you say that measurability intuitively means?

Comment: So are we not talking about [the same notion of measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function)? I am a bit confused...

Comment: This is more like the intuitive sense, not the formal sense.

Comment: @StanTendijck But how do you link both, intuitive and formal sense? I don't get it...

Comment: I don't think I can help you any further. I believe your problem is: why is the conditional expectation measurable? Not per se what is the conditional expectation. In the more formal sense, the expression I gave you is measurable since it consists of a linear combination of indicator functions with sets, elements of the sigma algebra. If you have a different set $B$ and you say that this event happened then we don't know per se whether $A$ happened or not and you can't conclude stuff about the above expression.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of that answer, $\mathbf E(X|\mathcal F)$ is the best guess of a random variable $X$ in view of the information contained in $\mathcal F$.

In some cases (as in the parity example in the answer) the best estimate of $X$ given $\mathcal F$ is not a fixed number but it depends on the specific value in $\mathcal F$. In the die example

$$\mathbf E(Die|Parity) = \begin{cases}4 & \text{if $Parity=Even$},\\
3& \text{if $Parity = Odd$},\end{cases}$$

This means that $\mathbf{E}(X|\mathcal F)$ is a random variable, however its value can be uniquely determined using information in $\mathcal F$ (that is, wether the die rolled is odd or even); hence, $\mathbf{E}(X|\mathcal F)$ has to be $\mathcal F$-measurable.