# Reference for conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, conditional-expectation

I am having problem understanding the idea of conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra. Is there any reference which explains the concept in detail. I will prefer something which does not go to geometric intuitions such as orthogonal projections.

Comment: Cinlar, "Probability and stochastics," covers everything from first principles.

Comment: I was only able to understand the notion of the conditional expectation with respect to a sub-$σ$-algebra $\mathcal G$, when I realized that this game is only interesting when $\mathcal G$ is "not Hausdorff", meaning that there might be points $x$ and $y$ which cannot be separated by a $\mathcal G$-measurable set.  Any $\mathcal G$-measurable function must therefore coincide on $x$ and $y$, so $E(X|\mathcal G)$ tries to be the best photograph of the random variable $X$ which coincides on $x$ and $y$, as well as on any other similar pairs of points.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ as an approximation to a random variable $X$ that is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Eventually, it turns out to be the best possible $\mathcal{G}$-measurable approximation according to the least squares criterion. But you came here for references:

1. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) is fine to see the evolution of the concept, and it is necessary to fully understand the following references.
2. [Rick Durrett's book](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/pte.html) explains the modern definition in detail.
3. This [document](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall18/sta711/lec/wk-10.pdf) clarifies the relationships between conditional expectation and conditional distributions, which, I think, is the core of the concept.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the equation $$\mathbb{E}(Y\mid B)=\mathbb{E}(Y\mid \sigma (B))(B) $$.
What I understand is that $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid \sigma(B))$ is  a $\sigma(B)$ measurable function .But I dont understand how it can be evaluated at B instead of $\omega \in \Omega$ like other random variables.

Comment: @smbch $\sigma(B)=\{\emptyset,\Omega,B,\Omega\setminus B\}$, and you can explicitly show that $E(Y|\sigma(B))$ is constant in $B$, so it is just an abuse of notation. $E(Y|B)$ is referring to the classical definition (see wikipedia) of conditional expectation with respect to an event (which is a number).

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Tenorio  Okay thanks.Will it be possible to give a reference which works this out in detail?

Comment: @smbch if you are refering to the proof that $E(Y|\sigma(B))$ is constant over $B$, it is fully detailed on Durrett's book (the begining of chapter $4$).

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Tenorio  I cant seem to find it. Can you please tell the page number?

Comment: @smbch It is a particular case of the example 4.1.5 (page 208)