# What makes the conditional expectation an expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

**Background**

I am self-studying measure-theoretic probability from the book by Robert Ash.

**Definitions**

1. If $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, then the **expectation** of $X$ is defined by
   $$ E(X) = \int_\Omega X \; dP, \quad \quad (1)$$
   provided the integral exists.
2. Let $Y$ be an extended random variable on  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and let $E[Y]$ exist.  Then for all $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$, there exists an extended random variable $h$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{G})$ such that:
   \begin{align*} 
    \int_{\mathcal{G}} Y \, dP = \int_{\mathcal{G}} h  \, dP \quad \quad \forall G \in \mathcal{G}.  
   \end{align*}
   We define the **conditional expectation** (of $Y$ given the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{G}$) by
   $$ E[Y \, | \, \mathcal{G}] := h$$

**Question**

What justifies the use of the term *expectation* in the name *conditional expectation*?  After all, the *conditional expectation* is not defined in terms of an integral, as in (1), but *implicitly*, as an integrand.  Is the answer simply that it *behaves* like an expectation (because it has properties like monotonicity, linearity, triangle inequality, monotone convergence, dominated convergence, Fatou's Lemma, etc.)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23600/305862